# Extracts the data from Document using webcam

Tags: php, camera, scanning

Can anyone recommend me a opensource solution for scanning the text or numeric information from the document via a webcam?

example:

User holds document  up to their device camera, script must scans the document, extracts the data it contains and feeds the date into Database.

Can anyone recommend anything?

Answer (score 0):

There is no read-to-use application for such task. You will have to combine things, which means programming in this case.

- there are webcam capture applications out there, just use one of them as executable. If you really need integrate it instead of calling an external executable, then either check the source of those utilities or see below
- the "opencv" framework (library) is probably a good starting point. It offers a number of typical and easy to use features like image manipulation, webcam capturing and the like. And it brings bindings to various languages
- you need some kind of OCR code. Few choices under Linux if you want to have a usable result: tesseract or cuneiform
- in addition you need to recognize the structure of the picture, that obviously depends on your document layout

You might want to take a look at existing examples for "number plate recognition" solutions. There are quite a few and they come close to what you are looking for.

Comment: I found this http://www.jumio.com/fastfill/how-it-works/

very similar what I want

can someone help?

Comment: Looks proprietary, no one can help with that except the company itself.